# Email open tracker not working when sending mail using laravel scheduler

Tags: php, laravel, email

In my laravel project backend, I need to track bulk email open, clicks, bounce etc. I am using a pixel image to track mails. When sending emails normally using loop the tracking is working fine. But when sending mails using cron scheduling, mail open tracking is not working. What is the problem ?

My controller:

```
Mail::to($this->email)->send(new MarketingMail($this->subject,$this->template,$this->id,  $this->email, $this->file_urls ? $this->file_urls : ''));
```

Code in mailable class:

```
class MarketingMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public $subject;
    public $template;
    public $id;
    public $email;
    public $file_url;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     */
    public function __construct($subject,$template,$id, $email, $file_url)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->template = $template;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->file_url = $file_url;
    }

    /**
     * Get the message envelope.
     */
    public function envelope(): Envelope
    {
        return new Envelope(
            subject: $this->subject,
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the message content definition.
     */
    public function content(): Content
    {
        return new Content(
            view: 'mail.mail',
            with: ['template' => $this->template, 'id' => $this->id],
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the attachments for the message.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Attachment>
     */
    public function attachments()
    {
        if ($this->file_url) {
            foreach ($this->file_url as $file) {
                $this->attach(public_path($file));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ route('track_open',[$id]) }}" />
    {!! $template !!}
</body>
</html>
```

Tracking is working fine when sending mails normally. But when scheduling using cron, tracking is not working. What is the reason ?

Comment: When you open up the email that is sent from cron and look at the HTML, was is the contents of the `<img>` tag? Is it a relative path or absolute, including protocol and domain?

Comment: The img is broken in email and the img tag is appearing like this <img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_NaozNLGpCEjy0UkLyYzyaNRJBVIN71OKoH6C8Xhyw09gwM79JOGleALMEc7Qqxn7afY=s0-d-e1-ft#http://localhost/images/2995" class="CToWUd" data-bit="iit" jslog="138226; u014N:xr6bB; 53:WzAsMl0.">  when I open up console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I found the problem. In console, at the end of the image path there was appearing `http://localhost`. that is the problem and the path was coming from `APP_URL` of `.env` of laravel.
So I changed the value `APP_URL` to my domain in `.env` and now the tracking is working.